# Getting coverage for e2e tests in IntelliJ

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, code-coverage, e2e-testing, istanbul

I have manually instrumented my code using:
`istanbul instrument src --o temp --es-modules --config=.istanbul.yml`.

This is my .istanbul.yml:

`instrumentation:
  excludes: ['*.spec.js']
  extensions: ['.js','.jsx']`

Once it is instrumented I am running e2e tests using Selenium inside IntelliJ, using the run with coverage button.

The tests pass but at the end it only gives me coverage information of the *.e2e.js files and not the actual *.jsx file that the e2e test is running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript is executed in the browser, not by the test-runnner. So only the code that is used by the test-runner is included in the coverage. You need to instrument the front-end code and send it to the browser and collect the coverage from the browser.

Here is how it could work with istanbul and Selenium:

> 1. Instrument your front-end code with the istanbul
>      instrument command. (As far as I know, istanbul instrument writes out
>      instrumented code to disk, whereas istanbul cover does everything in
>      memory.)
> 2. Instead of sending the original JS code to the browser, send
>      the instrumented JS code. The really nice thing here, with Istanbul,
>      you don’t have to manually modify your source code at all to make this
>      all work. Istanbul does almost all of the work for us in the browser,
>      automatically.
> 3. Run your Selenium-based tests, and for each individual
>      driver in your tests, run a hook that will send the coverage results
>      from the browser to the backend test process.
> 4. Once you get the
>      coverage data in the test process, you can do whatever you want with
>      it. In this case, we will HTTP POST the data to a server which can
>      interpret and display the coverage results.
> 5. And that’s it!
>
> Read the full article : https://medium.com/@the1mills/front-end-javascript-test-coverage-with-istanbul-selenium-4b2be44e3e98

The article goes over all the details how to set it up.